# form submit doesn't submit file type input

Tags: jquery, forms

I have form appended to body dynamically:

the form is:

```
    <form action="" data-reply-form class="ckit-composer-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">'
   +'<div class="ckit-composer">'
        +'<textarea data-ckit-composer-textarea placeholder="Add your reply" autocomplete="off" name="message" class="form-control ckit-composer__textarea"></textarea>'
        +'<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" data-fileToUpload multiple>'
        +'</div>'
        +'<input type="hidden" name="c_id" value="">'     
    +'</form>
```

I trigger submit this way:

```
$('[data-fileToUpload]').change( function(event) {

      $('[data-reply-form]').submit();
});
```

And on the the other page:

```
$("[data-reply-form]").submit(function(){
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        console.debug(data);
    });
```

But it only logs out, message and c_id inputs..why is it not showing file input values? How do I get file inputs values, like name, size, tmp_name and so forth?

Comment: var files = $('input[name="fileToUpload"]')[0].files;
        console.log(files);

Answer (score 0):

forms with uploads should be sent using the POST method

try using this form tag

```
<form action="" data-reply-form class="ckit-composer-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">'
```

also you can access the files information by using

$_FILES

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

example: $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']

would give you the temporary file name of the file being sent via HTTP POST

Comment: still I'mm unable to get file input's value

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

```
                <html>
            <head>
            <script
                src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <form action="demo_check.php" data-reply-form
                    class="ckit-composer-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
                    <div class="ckit-composer">
                        <textarea data-ckit-composer-textarea placeholder="Add your reply"
                            autocomplete="off" name="message"
                            class="form-control ckit-composer__textarea"></textarea>
                        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileinput"
                            data-fileToUpload multiple>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="c_id" value="">
                </form>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                            $('[data-fileToUpload]').change( function(event) {

                                  $('[data-reply-form]').submit();
                            });

                            $("[data-reply-form]").submit(function(){
                                 var name = $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0].name;
                                 alert(name);
                                 var size = $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0].size;
                                 alert("size: "+size);
                        });
                    </script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: that's very well..but can I save the file with this info? How can I get tmp_name of the the file?

Comment: You can get temprory file name by following code...I have pasted another code,check it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

```
            <html>
        <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.12.1.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <input type="file" id="i_file" value="">
            <input type="button" id="i_submit" value="Submit">
            <br>
            <img src="" width="200" style="display: none;" />
            <br>
            <div id="disp_tmp_path"></div>


        <script type="text/javascript">
                $('#i_file').change( function(event) {
                    var tmppath = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
                        $("img").fadeIn("fast").attr('src',URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));

                        $("#disp_tmp_path").html("Temporary Path(Copy it and try pasting it in browser address bar) --> <strong>["+tmppath+"]</strong>");
                });
        </script>
        </body>

        </html>
```